# Early-exercise point of American Put

Tags: finance

Could you please help me?
In book Rüdiger Seydel "Tools for Computational Finance" in Chapter 4.5 "American Options as Free Boundary Problem" it is provided the following explanation for case $S>S_f$ , where $S_f$ is contact point:
If $S>S_f$, then early-exercise causes immediate loss, because
$-V+K-S<0$. 
Well, we have options so in case of early exercise we should borrow $1$ risky asset and seal it with price $K$. So our current payoff will be $K$.
Why here is $-V+K-S$ ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By the *definition* of $S_f$ (eqn 4.22), we have $V^{am}_P(S, t) > (K - S)^+$ whenever $S > S_f(t)$.  Rearranging, $-V^{am}_P + (K - S)^+ < 0$, so we have

$-V^{am}_P + K - S \leq -V^{am}_P + (K - S)^+ < 0$

Comment: I understand, why $−V_{P}^{am}+K−S<0$, but how this variable $−V_{P}^{am}+K−S$ is connected to exercise? I mean, we have bought option at some arbitrary moment $\hat{t}$ for price $V(S(\hat{t}),\hat{t})=\hat{V}$, and we exercise at another time moment $t$ when $S>S_{f}$, so we get payoff $K-S(t)$. So cashflow will be $-\hat{V} +K -S(t)$ and its not always less than zero (only $-V(S(t),t) +K -S(t) < 0$). Thank you. I hope you understood my question.